# Convert Dictionary<string, List<string>> to List<string> with concat Key/Value c#

Tags: c#

Is there a Linq/inline way of doing this without using foreach?

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> ErrorResults;

List<string> ErrorMessages;

//Concat <string>Key with List<string> values
ErrorMessages = ErrorResults.Select(s => $"{s.Key}: {s.Value.SelectMany(v => v)}");

//results should be:
//Key1: MessageValue1
//Key1: MessageValue1
//Key2: MessageValue1
//Key2: MessageValue2
//Key2: MessageValue3
//Key3: MessageValue1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use use `Select` to select a string for each item in the value, and `SelectMany` to get all the values as a single list:

```
List<string> ErrorMessages = ErrorResults
    .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value.Select(val => $"{kvp.Key}: {val}"))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Works Great! I was on that right track just had my select/selectmany backwards. Thanks!

Comment: @beatnikthedan: For what it's worth, that's why I strongly prefer the query comprehension syntax for SelectMany.  You don't need to think hard about what that lambda means; it's right there, written clearly in the query text.  For example, for my answer below: `from item in errorResults` says "for every item in errorResults" and then  `from msg in item.Value` for every message in each of those items' Value properties.  Now it have an `item` per Key and a collection of `msg` for each key.  At that point, I just need to `select $"{item.Key}: {msg}"`.  I'm also partial to this syntax for Joins.

Answer (score 0):

This should do?

```
var errorMessages = dic.Select(pair =>  pair.Value.Select(v => $"{pair.Key}: {v}" ) )
            .SelectMany(v => v) 
            .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I find `SelectMany` easier to figure out using the query comprehension syntax.  This works:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> errorResults = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    {"Key1", new List<string> {"MessageValue1a","MessageValue1b"}},
    {"Key2", new List<string> {"MessageValue2a", "MessageValue2b", "MessageValue2c"}},
    {"Key3", new List<string> {"MessageValue3"}},
};

var errorMessages = (from item in errorResults
    from msg in item.Value
    select $"{item.Key}: {msg}").ToList();
```

That results in strings containing:

```
Key1: MessageValue1a
Key1: MessageValue1b
Key2: MessageValue2a
Key2: MessageValue2b
Key2: MessageValue2c
Key3: MessageValue3
```

*For what it's worth*, it's a courtesy to your readers to include a full repro (including the code to initialize your `ErrorResult` dictionary).

Comment: you wouldn't want my full repo to get this working. It would take you forever to read it. It's a courtesy that I simplified it. But I usually do when it's practical. But I could have initialized some values

Comment: Not a full repro, but code similar to what I typed up to initialize my `errorResults` variable (which mostly matches what you show). A [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Equivalent using linq query format:

```cs
ErrorMessages = (
    from kvp in ErrorResults
    from val in kvp.Value
    select $"{kvp.Key}: {val}"
).ToList();
```